# Printing a CString prints unknown text before

Tags: c, printf

Unfortunately, this Code seems to prints something before it prints the actual text. What is this? And why is it printed?

"\300\367\277\357\376"

I realized this more often in my code and I am sure it implies I have done something wrong.

```
char* concat(const char *s1, const char *s2);
int main(int argv, char* args[]){
    char lastchars[50];
    char *buf;
    while(1){
        gets(lastchars);
        if(strlen(lastchars) == 0)break;
        buf = concat(buf, lastchars);
    }
    printf("%s",buf);
 }
 char* concat(const char *s1, const char *s2)
 {
    char *result = malloc(strlen(s1) + strlen(s2) + 1); 
    strcpy(result, s1);
    strcat(result, s2);
    return result;
 }
```

Comment: What is the definition of `concat`? Also, why not use the standard `strcat`?

Comment: You never initialized `buf`, so you're getting undefined behavior.

Comment: Also, never ever ever ever ever use `gets`!

Comment: [Why gets() is so dangerous it should never be used!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used)

Comment: After `char *buf;` -- What valid memory is `buf` pointing to? (hint: none you own)

Comment: [Pointer initialisation gives segmentation fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17873561/pointer-initialisation-gives-segmentation-fault) - roughly on point.

Comment: I added the definition concat which should explain the initializations troubles you have...

Comment: `strcpy(result, s1);` <- since `s1` is freshly allocated, it is uninitialized and you are copying garbage into your buffer, also `strlen` requires a null-terminated string, else its undefined behavior

Comment: Oh ... Did not expected this behaviour. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if we look past the call to the unsafe and no longer supported function `gets`, there are numerous problems with this code, starting with your `concat` function:

```
char* concat(const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
   char *result = malloc(strlen(s1) + strlen(s2) + 1); 
   strcpy(result, s1);
   strcat(result, s2);
   return result;
}
```

You are calling `concat` with the line: `buf = concat(buf, lastchars);` when `buf` is unintialized. In other words:

```
char *result = malloc(strlen(buf) + strlen(lastwords) + 1);
strcpy(result, buf);
strcat(result, lastwords);
return result;
```

What is `strlen(buf)`? This is undefined behavior since `buf` doesn't contain a string with a null-terminator.

Then, `strcpy(result, buf)` is also undefined behavior since `buf` isn't initialized.

Then you return `result` and assign it back into `buf`.

It is very difficult to decipher your intent with this code, so I cannot offer a solution - only point out the numerous problems.

Comment: I actually use a book of network programming, which code was written 1999. I never used C before... It is difficult to once learn network programming (or at least standard IO stuff, so far), learn C and differentiate between the old C and the new C... The old C is not well supported in those ages (Basically why it should...)
I am just trying to read my typed code into a file (excersice) Eventually my Overflow account will get banned soon, because of to many stupid questions...

Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Which 1999 networking text book, @TVSuchty?  Are you sure there isn't a more recent one that would do the job better.  Are you sure you copied the code correctly?  (It's far from impossible that there is an error such as you've typed, but it is not likely to be in a top-notch book, even from that era.)

Comment: No: I wrote the code, trying to extract the essence of the lecture.
It is a german book:
https://www.amazon.de/Unix-Netzwerkprogrammierung-mit-Threads-Sockets-X-systems-press/dp/3540002995/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1550094008&sr=8-2&keywords=netzwerkprogrammierung

Comment: I don't read German sufficiently well to be able to assess the book — I'm sorry.  I've not heard of it before; I've not seen any commentary on it.  Be cautious if this is really what it says, @TVSuchty.  It might be an isolated problem; it might be indicative of other problems in the examples.  It gets reasonable reviews at Amazon, but that isn't as reliable as anyone would like.